# Neo4j: use in a projection a virtual relationship with weights

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I can create a relationship in my graph, assign weights and write in disk as follows:

```
MATCH (a1:node1)-[rel1]-(p:other_node)-[rel2]-(a2:node2)
// create the weight
with a1.id as id1, a2.id as id2, count(p) as common_ocurrences
// create the rel
MERGE (a1)-[r:NEW_REL]-(a2)
// use the weights as a property of the created relationship
ON CREATE SET r.counter = common_occurrences
ON MATCH SET r.counter = common_occurrences

// create projection 
CALL gds.graph.project(
 'new-graph',
 'node1',
 {NEW_REL:{
 orientation:'UNDIRECTED',
 properties:'counter'
 }
 }
)
yield *
```

but what i want is to do the same, without writing the relationship nor the associated weight.
for that i tried using **virtual relationships** like with this method:

```
MATCH (a1:node1)-[rel1]-(p:other_node)-[rel2]-(a2:node2)
with a1, a2, count(p) as common_occurrences
where a1.id>a2.id
return 
a1, a2, 
apoc.create.vRelationship(a1, 'COAUTHORS_WITH_VIRTUAL2', {weight: common_occurrences}, a2) as REL_VIRTUAL2;
```

this part seems to work but now i'm quite puzzled about how to use it. if right after the last clause i write something like

```
CALL gds.graph.project(
 'graph42',
 'node1',
 {REL_VIRTUAL_2:{
 orientation:'UNDIRECTED',
 properties:'common_occurrences'
 }
 }

)
yield *
```

it says that the relationship can not be found.
any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with both of your queries.

For example, `REL_VIRTUAL2` is just a temporary variable name, not a relationship type. `COAUTHORS_WITH_VIRTUAL2` is the relationship type you should have used in the projection. However, changing that would still not fix things because **GDS does not support projecting virtual nodes or relationships**.

Your first approach should work, but you may need to solve some other issues first. For example, the projection should use `['node1', 'node2']` instead of just `'node1'` for the node labels,. And you can replace `ON CREATE SET x = y ON MATCH SET x = y` with just `SET x = y`.